# Dynamic template of a directive, different resolving behaviour for wrapper and inner elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Been working with angular for a few months now, it has been only a week or so since I dove into directives. And today I met this little quirk while trying to build a settings page with a checkbox field being dependent on another (as in - shown only if another checkbox field is checked).

I found that there's ng-disabled that could work, but I figured I rather hide the whole field if the other one isn't cheched, + I figured I can use ng-show on the raw html to do exactly that, but I'm so fascinated with directives that I want to understand how it's done from the inside.

So, here's the HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="mdl.show" />
  <span>Switches 'mdl.show' on and off, now it's {{mdl.show}}</span>
  <div spg dependent="mdl.show"></div>
</form>
```

And the controller:

```
app.controller('appCtrl',['$scope',
  function($scope){
    $scope.mdl = {show: true};
  }
])
```

And the directive:

```
app.directive('spg',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function (element,attrs){
        var html = '<div data-ng-show="' + attrs.dependent + '">';
        html += '<p data-ng-show="' + attrs.dependent + '">This text doesn\'t show if dependent resolves to false</p>';
        html += '<p>For some reason, even though div wrapper has the same configuration as the previous \'p\' - this one will show either way</p>'
        html += '</div>';
        angular.element(element).replaceWith(html);
    }
  }
})
```

And [here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/D07PHhzGlO9URMtTtvu7?p=preview) that plunk.
Much more than receiving a solution to this problem, I prefer to understand why it happens at all. Though both are very welcome. Thanks.

Edit: Same behaviour with both 1.0.7 and 1.2.0rc1.

Comment: Looking at this from the angular documentation: The show and hide mechanism is a achieved by removing and adding the ng-hide CSS class onto the element. That's true when I inspect what's going on on the ng-show page from the angular site but it doesn't work like that in your plunk, which sets the style attribute of the inner <p> to display:none. I'm not sure that gets you any closer to solving it, but they changed the behavior at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your code doesn't work, but I do know you don't need to use the `compile` function unless your directive does template transformation, which is rarely needed for custom directives. Most directives only need to implement the `link` function and/or the `controller` function.

In your case, none is required for the directive to work. The following code works just fine:

```
app.directive('spg',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { visible: '=' },
    template: '<div ng-show="visible">' +
              '<p>This text doesn\'t show if dependent resolves to false</p>' +
              '<p>For some reason, even though div wrapper has the same configuration as the previous \'p\' - this one will show either way</p>' +
              '</div>',
  };
});
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tlKUMBtFZEnR8Vn0vWGA?p=preview).

Perhaps this answer isn't what you were expecting, but I think this issue in particular isn't really something to worry about. If you want to learn more about the `compile` function, [this](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/05/13/understanding-angularjs-directives-part1-ng-repeat-and-compile/) article should get you started. The [dev guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) has some valuable information as well.

Comment: I'm using the compile function since in my real use case I have some of the text in side 'p' + a header + the type of the header + amodel to assign an input field to and a few other things - all coming from the attrs and compiled accordingly. So I believe I do need the compile function. Thanks for the links =]

Comment: Are you planning on doing template transformations, like ng-repeat does?

Comment: Something along these lines, it's a custom form constructor that allows simple model-based-dependency and is as-DRY-as-i-can. Currently the directive isn't saving any bytes, quite the opposite. But it certainly will ease maintenance.